# Cannot get connections from LinkedIn python API

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am trying to get LinkedIn connections through its python API.

Now **the code can call get_profile()** function, but when I tried `application.get_connections()`, it gives me the error showing:

> linkedin.exceptions.LinkedInError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections?oauth2_access_token=...

My linkedin application permissions only have 4 choices:
r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, rw_company_admin, w_share

The redirect url I am using is http://localhost/

So, do you know how can I get LinkedIn connections through python API?

My code:

```
from linkedin import linkedin as lk

new_token = [my token]

application = lk.LinkedInApplication(token=new_token)

p = application.get_profile()     # this one works
c = application.get_connections()
print p
print c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [connections API](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api) requires the `r_network` scope to be granted by the user.  According to this LinkedIn [doc](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition), certain scopes have been restricted and require developers to apply to LinkedIn's partner program to gain access to them.

Note: it also appears that [this](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) is the library you are using.

Comment: I think LinkedIn has revoked the access of `r_network` scope. Here's what they say [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) _"ensure that the scope parameter in your authorization workflow is no longer requesting any of the following member permissions: `r_fullprofile`, `r_network`, `r_contactinfo`, `rw_nus`, `rw_groups`, `w_messages`."_